# Не работает код (java) в определенных условиях

Tags: java, keypress

Основная задача состоит в том чтобы к примеру раз в 3 секунды нажималась определенна кнопка в игре. Опустил пока слип и цикл. Проблема всего одна: код имитирует нажатие кнопки 2 везде кроме игры. Т.е. если активен блокнот - будет писать цифру 2 и т.д. Но стоит сделать активным окном саму игру - событие которое должно вызываться нажатием кнопки 2 не происходит.

```
Robot bot = new Robot();
bot.keyPress(KeyEvent.VK_2);
```

Подскажите пожалуйста в чём проблема?

Comment: Проблема, скорее всего, связана с тем, что ваш робот (Robot) отправляет событие клавиши независимо от текущего активного окна. Для того чтобы эмулировать нажатие клавиши только в активном окне, вам, возможно, придется использовать библиотеку, поддерживающую взаимодействие с GUI (графическим интерфейсом пользователя) и окнами.

Comment: Так ведь в активном окне работает, если это окно не игра, т.е. будь активным окном какой то текстовый редактор или окошко поиска - напишет букву и т.д. Кстати bot.mousePress(InputEvent.BUTTON1_MASK); имеет тот же эффект - т.е. в любом окне будь то папка, IDEA, блокнот и т.п. - клик работает - но стоит навести курсор на окно игры - увы - ничего не происходит. Если нужен импорт какой то библиотеки для взаимодействия - подскажите пожалуйста в сторону какой копать. Потому как всё что нагуглил это библиотеки для "создания" окон и только.

Answer (score 0):

Вопрос решён. Проблема не в коде. Проблема оказалась в защите самой игры, там стоит что то вроде GameGuard, я просто первый раз столкнулся с такими вещами. Теперь буду придумывать как это обойти.